# No internet connection when connected to hostednetwork

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, hotspot

I setup a hostednetwork on my Windows 10 machine, which is sharing a connection. I tried connecting two devices to my hostednetwork, but neither of the devices have internet access (even though they connected fine). Also, the connection (on host machine) states "Access type: Internet", so I'd think it'd be fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Restarting my host computer fixed the issue.